# Possible ways of retrieing a Javascript value to Servlet etc

Tags: javascript, servlets

Suppose, I'm working with Java servlet, JSP, JSTL/EL or JSF. As far as I know, one of the most general ways to retrieve a value of a Javascript variable to simply say Servlet is to store that value into a hidden field using Javascript and retrieve the value of that hidden field through the request parameters `HttpservletRequest.getParameter("someParameter");`. Are there any possible ways that might be more better than this.

Comment: Requests send parameters in the URL itself, or in the request body--that's how HTTP works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the additional frameworks you use or don't there are some wrappers, not necessary different ways.

For instance [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) does full javascript->java and back, never have to use a form submit again.   Its a pretty solid project though it has been at 3.0b for like 3 years.

From the client you can do an ajax call of course.  Depending on what javascript library you use (and please use one) I suggest [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can pass any javascript variable.  The issue becomes decoding it on the other side.

If you want something a little more standard check out RestEasy a JAXRS implementation that supports javascript serialization.   It can do some more advanced mapping between request parameters and java objects.

If you are using servlet and can't use a 3rd party library you can still make calls via AJAX  such as

```
  var your_data_obj = { key:'value', number:1}
    jQuery.ajax('/path/to/servlet', { data:your_data_obj, success:function(obj){ alert('me'+obj);
 })
```

Comment: +1, although ultimately its still just sugar and marshalling data out of the request body or URL.